# what should i do to remove the error of importing nltk as i have already installed it?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, nltk

I have installed nltk and now it's not working, and I need assistance figuring out what's wrong. I installed via pip

It is showing these error.

> Please use the `NLTK Downloader` to obtain the resource

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this.

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing nltk gives you access to the code, but nltk relies on internal datasets, which you need to download separately.

You need to run `nltk.download()` to get access to them.

[More information here](https://www.nltk.org/data.html).